# Can't choose the correct end date from the datepicker in a Python script

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, datepicker

I'm using Google Chrome browser. I'm running a python script to choose the correct dates in the datepicker. It is unable to select the correct date. It keeps selecting the end date to be "02/01/2022" but I want to choose the date of five (5) days ago from today's date every time I run the script. For example, today is "02/08/2022" so it should choose "02/03/2022" as the end date. The start date, "12/01/2021" is correct.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os.path
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import calendar
import datetime
from datetime import date

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/myname/Documents/chromedriver", options=chrome_options)

todays_date = date.today()
print(todays_date)

driver.get("https://accessdata.broadridge.com/node952064/")
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input')))
    print("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/span/img').click()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="span8"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ext-gen157"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/img').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ext-gen209"]').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[11]/a').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dateAnchor1_0"]/img').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="caldiv"]/table/tbody/tr/td/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a').click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'dateAnchor2_0').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="caldiv"]/table/tbody/tr/td/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a').click()
```

How can I select the correct date for five days ago from today?

Here's the HTML code:

```
<td align="left" nowrap="">
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        
                        
                            <td align="right" nowrap="">
                                <div id="firstValue1_0" style="visibility: visible">
                                    <input type="text" name="values1" value="12/01/2021" size="11" maxlength="10" onkeypress="if(document.getElementById('firstCalendar1_0').style.visibility == 'visible' ) return processKeyPress(this); else return true;" onfocus="self.status='Date Format is ' + dtFormat;" onblur="self.status=' ';" onchange="if(document.getElementById('firstCalendar1_0').style.visibility == 'visible' ){if(isValidDate(this)) valueOnChange(0);} else valueOnChange(0);">&nbsp;

                                    <span id="firstValue3_0" style="display: none">% may be used as a wildcard character. </span>
                                
                                
                                    
                                    
                                        
                                        
                                            <div id="firstCalendar1_0" style="visibility: visible;display:inline">
                                        
                                    
                                

                                        <a id="dateAnchor1_0" name="dateAnchor1_0" onclick="dateSelect(0, 'values1');" style="vertical-align:middle"><img border="0" src="images/calendar.gif"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </td>
                            <td valign="center" nowrap="">
                                <div id="firstValue2_0" style="display: none">
                                    <span id="search0" class="search_sm" onclick="popupSearch('810', 'values1', 'Trade Date', 0)" onmouseover="doImgSwapOver('search_sm',0,true)" onmouseout="doImgSwapOut('search_sm',0,true)">
                                        <img name="search_sm" src="images/btn_search_sm.gif" width="24" height="22" alt="Search Trade Date" border="0" align="absmiddle">
                                    </span>
                                    <a name="searchAnchor0" id="searchAnchor0"></a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        
                        

                        
                        

                        <td valign="center" nowrap="">
                            
                                <div id="secondValue1_0" style="visibility: visible">
                            
                            
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;and&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </div>
                        </td>
                        
                            <td valign="center" nowrap="">
                                
                                    <div id="secondValue2_0" style="visibility: visible">
                                
                                
                                        <input type="text" name="values2" value="02/03/2022" size="11" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return processKeyPress(this);" onfocus="self.status='Date Format is ' + dtFormat;" onblur="self.status=' ';" onchange="if(isValidDate(this)) valueOnChange(0);">
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <a id="dateAnchor2_0" name="dateAnchor2_0" onclick="dateSelect(0, 'values2');">
                                            <img border="0" src="images/calendar.gif">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                            </td>
                        
                        

                        

                        <td>
                        
                        </td>

                        
                        <td valign="center" nowrap="">

                        <!-- visibility -->
                        
                        <div id="tinMask_0" style="visibility:hidden">
                        

                        <!-- Tin Mask Selection Box -->
                        <table>
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- Previously set to SHOW -->
                                    

                                    <!-- Previously set to HIDE  -->
                                    
                                        

                                        <!-- Not previously set -->
                                        
                                            <!-- Tin Privileges -->
                                            
                                            <!-- No Tin Privileges -->
                                            
                                                <select name="tinMaskFlgs" onchange="flagOnChange(0,document.forms[0].tinMaskFlgs,document.forms[0].columnFilterTinMaskFlgs);">
                                                    <option value="false">Show Tin Values</option>
                                                    <option value="true" selected="">Hide Tin Values </option>
                                                </select>
                                            
                                         <!-- true -->
                                     <!-- false -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                        </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I had to clear the value first.

```
import calendar
import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

date_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'values2')
date_element.clear()
five_days_prior = datetime.now() - timedelta(5)
end_date = five_days_prior.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
date_element.send_keys(end_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element(BY_NAME,"values2").send_keys("02/03/2022")
```

You can try sending keys to the input tag with the name values2.

Comment: It didn't work, unfortunately. But thanks!